# How do i fix my keyboard mapping?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

I am using Gnome3/Gnome Shell/Ubuntu 11.10.  Today, when I began using my machine, it would not co-operate with me.  Trying to type simple documents, my **SHIFT-p** was captured -- and spawned an xterm window!

I have no idea how I may have caused this anomaly.  But I searched the various locations trying to find the culprit...

I checked the "Shortcuts" tab of the "System Settings|Hardware|Keyboard" applet... no assignment to **SHIFT-p** in any of these lists...

I checked the Commands panel in "CompizConfig Settings Manager" (from Gnome Menu|Other)... no assignment there either.

After reading some other related keymapping issues asked in askubuntu, I brought up the xev application to see what it would report...  while programmatically pressing each key on the keyboard, examining the report from xev, I learned that **SHIFT-w-w** is also mapped to bring up an xterm!

while exploring, it appears (using ps -ef), that both commands are mapped to "sh -c xterm"...

How can I fix this?  I don't know where to turn next.

> ps -ef

reports three processes being initiated each time I press **SHIFT-p** (or **SHIFT-w-w**):

```
* sh -c xterm
* xterm
* bash
```

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot this problem?

**UPDATE**

> The problem boiled down to an issue with my **.xbindkeysrc.scm** file.
>   I had explored a tutorial on the topic some weeks back and had
>   downloaded a tutorial (**.xbindkeysrc.scm**) file.  After playing with
>   the tutorial for a little while, I disabled the file.
>
> When doing some housekeeping on my system this morning, I
>   inadvertently re-enabled the file.  This caused the mysterious
>   behavior.

Comment: So, I went to a console and tried to reproduce the problem.  But failed.  This led me to realize that it was specific to the X environment.  After digging around, I realized it was due to settings in my .xbindkeysrc.scm file!

Comment: So this can be deleted... (But I'm not sure how to do that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boiled down to an issue with my .xbindkeysrc.scm file. I had explored a tutorial on the topic some weeks back and had downloaded a tutorial (.xbindkeysrc.scm) file. After playing with the tutorial for a little while, I disabled the file.

When doing some housekeeping on my system this morning, I inadvertently re-enabled the file. This caused the mysterious behavior.